# I have installed Ubuntu 13.04, but it can't work normally

Tags: installation, boot

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 amd64 successfully, but it can't boot normally. The computer is dead after displaying the logo Ubuntu and the screen is red. Strangely, booting from recovery mode then repairing packages, it can boot normally.

What can I do?

I think the problem is too difficult for me, I decide to abandon Ubuntu. Thank you all very much

Comment: What do you mean by "boot normally"? It sounds like you had an issue and then solved it.

Comment: No, I didn't solved the problem."boot normally" only after "booting from recovery mode then repairing packages".

Comment: Can you provide more information? For example, what packages does it try to install?

Comment: I have found that booting from recovery mode-resume also works, so I  thought it's wrong with the graphical driver, then i fixed the problem. Thank you

Comment: *"I used the command sudo apt-get install nvidia-current to fix the problem and it works."* Please post answers as answers. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question on this site! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is caused by the graphical card, mine is NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430].

I used the command

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

to fix the problem and it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the energy saving settings. When you boot Ubuntu Live CD or even installed on hard drive, the screen is dimmed to 0%. Try bringing up the brightness of the screen with the combination that works in Windows (Fn+F3). This worked for me.

For a more persistent workaround, try adding in your `/etc/default/grub`, in the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, the option `acpi_backlight=vendor`. (Editing that file will work only as root.)  Then issue `update-grub` as root, as suggested in the header of the file. Source: I did not have the time to try it, but it is mentioned at http://larrymulcahy.blogspot.com/2013/08/hp-envy-17t-j000-laptop-2.html

Answer (score -1):

Check whether your computer supports 64 Bit Operating System or not?

If it supports ...
Try re installing Ubuntu once again and follow these instructions:

1.Boot from Live CD/DVD/USB and follow the installation process 
2.format the System and swap drives 
3.the make the partition of swap at least 1 GB
4.remaining with the system install Ubuntu
5.then Your system will normally boot

Comment: I think my computer supports 64 Bit Operating System. I have installed Ubuntu many times, but it can't work