# NVIDIA GeForce 6150 GE Crash Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I decided to do a clean install of Ubuntu 13.04 on my desktop computer. It worked fine for the first 30 minutes or so but then the graphics crashed (after I had logged in so there is no problem with the computer).

**mini-pc eMachines® EL1200-07w:**

- CPU: AMD Athlon™ 64 Processor 1.6GHz
- Chipset: NVIDIA® GeForce® 6150SE
- Memory: 2048MB DDR2 (2 × 1024MB) -Expandable to 4GB-
- Hard Drive: 160GB SATA II
- Video: NVIDIA® GeForce® 6150SE integrated graphics (Up to 128MB of shared video memory)

Comment: Have you looked at related links? [This one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/337034/i-have-installed-ubuntu-13-04-but-it-cant-work-normally/337561#337561), [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/85913/video-drivers-for-onboard-geforce-6150se), or even [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/231972/nvidia-geforce-6150se-nforce-430). Not all of them may be helpful, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed a clean installation, you are using nouveau drivers. Those driver generate a lot of problems, and specially with the 6150 graphics card. I have the same nvidia card than you, and the only solution was installing the propietary drivers of nvidia, and configuring the system to use nonfree drivers.

With this solution the system is more stable, but still hangs sometimes. I recommend you using a lighter desktop environment .Unity 3D is still very unstable, because it depends of the stability of the drivers. With unity 2d there was no problem, but Canonical thought that it was no cool and retired that option. Use Xubuntu or Lubuntu to improve stability on your system (and speed).